# Proof that $B(x, \delta)=\text{Int}(B(x, \delta))$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider

$$B(x, \delta)=\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n: d(x, y)< \delta \}$$

I want to show that $B(x, \delta)=Int(B(x, \delta))$, evidently $Int(B(x, \delta)) \subseteq B(x, \delta)$, so for the other contention take $y \in B(x, \delta)$ for some $\delta >0$ then

$$d(x, y) < \delta$$

We want to prove that $y$ is an interior point of the open ball, and this is true if there exists

$$C_{n}=I_{1} \times \dots \times I_{n}$$

From where $I_{j}$ is a open of $\mathbb{R}$, s.t. $y \in C_{n}$ and $C_{n} \subseteq B(x, \delta)$

Now, my question is how to build such a box that will allow me to display the missing content? any suggestions?

Comment: In fact, the thing is to find an open set which contain any element of $B(x,\delta)$, which means no need to find a open ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interior of an open set is the open set itself, but assuming you don't want to use this fact, the way to construct the ball/box is to define $\epsilon :=d(x,y) < \delta$ and $r:=\delta - \epsilon > 0$.
Then the ball $B(y,\frac{r}{2}) \subset B(x,\delta)$. To see this, note that if $z \in B(y,\frac{r}{2})$ then $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z) < \epsilon + \frac{r}{2} < \epsilon + r = \delta$.

Comment: I see, as far as I understand in our case $C_{n}:=B(y, \frac{r}{2})$, right?

Comment: Yes and note that it's an open ball, but if you insist on a literal "box" then in finite-dimensional spaces all the p-norms are equivalent. In particular, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \|x\|_{2} \leq \|x \|_{\infty}$. So you can inscribe a box inside any ball because of this relation. In our example it would be $ \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n :  \|x-y \|_{\infty} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{r}{2} \}$ which is a box inside $B(y,\frac{r}{2})$.